# Not able to iterate a list of map<string, string> using java

Tags: java

I'm trying to iterate a list object which internally has map.. Here is my code

```
public Response updateStatus(List<Map<String, String>> leadIds) {
    Iterator it = leadIds.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        LOG.info("Key: "+pairs.getKey() + " Value: " + pairs.getValue());
    }
```

Lead id's has the following values

```
[{Id=1066276530, Key1=1815401000238}, {Id=1059632250, Key1=1815401000244}]
```

But, I'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
```

Comment: Which java version do you use?

Comment: Based on your code, `it.next()` will give you a `Map` and not `Map.Entry`. `it` is the iterator for the list and not map.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan, Can you please with a small snippet?

Comment: Check out Eran's answer. You will need two iterators and hence 2 loops..

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops to iterate over the Maps contained within the List :

```
public Response updateStatus(List<Map<String, String>> leadIds) {
    Iterator<Map<String, String>> listIt = leadIds.iterator();
    while (listIt.hasNext()) {
      Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = listIt.next().entrySet().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
          Map.Entry<String,String> pairs = it.next();
          LOG.info("Key: "+pairs.getKey() + " Value: " + pairs.getValue());
      }
    }
}
```

BTW, Java 8 offers a shorter API for such iteration :

```
leadIds.stream()
       .flatMap(m->m.entrySet().stream())
       .forEach(entry -> {
                          LOG.info("Key: "+entry.getKey() + " Value: " + entry.getValue());
                         });
```

Comment: Eran, it says incompatible types. It requires java.util.iterator

Comment: @Nizam Sorry about that. Fixed. Forgot to add `.iterator()` after `.entrySet()`

Comment: Eran, have you tested the first part?

Comment: @Nizam I just did. It passes compilation (after I remove the Response  return type of the method and change Log.info to System.out.println). Note that the original version had a problem that I later fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do this:

```
public Response updateStatus(List<Map<String, String>> leadIds) {
    for (Map<String, String> map : leadIds) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            LOG.info("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

This code has been tested and appears to be working correctly.  One caveat: The call to `map.entrySet()` returns a `Set` containing the entries, and it seems to be unordered.  So my code definitely *will* log all key/value pairs, but not necessarily in a particular order.

Comment: It should be entry, right

Comment: Have you tried this? or Its just an assumption?

Comment: sure will let you know after testing

Comment: @Nizam Have you tested the code yet?

Comment: Its not right.. Its not returning the right value.. Its returning as Application Number :1066276530 ID :Id

Comment: This comment give me no way to help you.  What are the key/value pairs you expect, and what are you seeing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81614/discussion-between-nizam-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I've put in chat. Can you please reply there? I'm expecting 1066276530 as Key  and value as 1815401000238 etc

Answer (score 0):

You need a second loop.
Change To:

```
public Response updateStatus(List<Map<String, String>> leadIds) {
    Iterator<Map<String, String>> it = leadIds.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, String> m = it.next();
        Iterator it1 = m.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it1.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>) it1
                    .next();
              LOG.info("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```